# How do I put the weather in the menu bar?

Tags: gnome, 15.10

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 and was checking for my town weather. there is a `weather` app by default in Gnome but It had to run each time. I want to add it to top menu bar.

Also I tried to Install other app but get following message in terminal.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm5yE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `indicator-weather` was recently available for Ubuntu 12.10. In 15.10 you have to use a GNOME extension.

1. **Use your Firefox browser and open [this](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/750/openweather/) URL**
2. **Activate the extension.**

   [image]
3. **Run <kbd>Tweak Tool</kbd>**

   [image]
4. **Configure the extension**

   [image]